# Git "mirror" repo

Tags: git

I have a remote (GitHub) library repository that I cloned and I use it as a **submodule** in my Android project, however I had to change a bit the **gradle** file so it could build properly on my project. Now, since I don't own the repository, I wish to add it into my company repo but i want to be able to merge from the origin (Gihub) repo.

Which is the best usual approach here ?

Basically I want to be able to do commits and push to our company repo, but from time to time merge any changes from the original repository onto our "copy"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fork the repository on GitHub. Clone it locally. Make your commits. When it comes time to integrate changes from the original repository, add another remote and fetch + merge.

```
git clone https://github.com/your_forked_repo.git
cd your_forked_repo
# hack, hack, hack. commit.
git remote add upstream https://github.com/the_repo_you_forked_from.git
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master
```